# How to determine ethernet port capability with RHEL operating systems

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, redhat-enterprise-linux, hardware-detection

I am not quite sure how to word this..as you can tell by the slightly vague title. I recently purchased an MSI WE72 7RJ-1032US Mobile Workstation Laptop in hopes of making it into a development machine for personal use. It came with windows 10 on it, and I was able to access a LAN Ethernet connection with no problem. However, when installing RHEL 6.9 on the machine, it fails to recognize that the port even exists (i.e. `ll /sys/class/net` did not include the ethernet device). I was able to pull the MAC address off of the Windows image prior to re-imaging it, but do not know how to proceed from here. What should my next steps in debugging this issue be? Or am I completely hosed?

Comment: You use `lspci -nn` and throw the numbers into Google.

Comment: "lspci |grep -i eth " should show only the ethernet devices, which you have to check being supported by rhel6.

Comment: Thank you! I had to install kmod-alx and that seemed to resolve the issues

Answer (score 0):

Using *lspci -nn* I was able to determine the required kernel module for the ethernet chipset and then using yum to install, it resolved all of my missing interface issues.